# Why my RX 480 Samsung have slightly lower Mh/s when mixed with a bunch of hynix?

Tags: mining

This is a very minor problem

This is the result of my mining speed

```
ETH - Total Speed: 176.250 Mh/s, Total Shares: 164, Rejected: 0, Time: 01:03
ETH: GPU0 29.310 Mh/s, GPU1 30.241 Mh/s, GPU2 29.269 Mh/s, GPU3 29.297 Mh/s, GPU4 28.826 Mh/s, GPU5 29.261 Mh/s
GPU0 t=57C fan=71%
ETH: 04/24/17-09:03:41 - New job from europe.ethash-hub.miningpoolhub.com:17020
ETH - Total Speed: 176.020 Mh/s, Total Shares: 164, Rejected: 0, Time: 01:03
ETH: GPU0 29.307 Mh/s, GPU1 30.220 Mh/s, GPU2 29.174 Mh/s, GPU3 29.275 Mh/s, GPU4 28.750 Mh/s, GPU5 29.294 Mh/s
Setting DAG epoch #19...
```

GPU 1 is samsung and doing 30.220 mh/s as expected.

GPU4 is also samsung with the same set up. 1190 clockspeed and 2135 memory speed. It's doing only 28.750 mh/s

The rest are hynix doing normal 29.25 mh/s

I wonder why.

If I remove the 4 hynix card then both samsung will clock 30.220 mh/s

```
GPU-z       Watttool    Wattool PCI-e   Claymore    power   voltage mem voltage 
1           0           0       0       1   75  910 900 samsung
0           4           20      1       4       910 900 samsung
2           2           8       2       5       910 900 
3           3           14      3       2       910 900 
4           1           2       4       3       910 900 
5           5           36      5       0       910 900
```

I know that claymore #4 correspond to wattool number 4 too in my graph (index 20). I know that by pressing 4 in claymore and see that GPU go up and down on the correct index at watttool.

[image]

You can see that this is the exact same set up with Claymore #1 (watttool 0)

And somehow GPU1 makes 30.220 mh/s and GPU 4 a mere 28.750 mh/s.

Comment: Turns out I found out what the problem is. The GPU clock is only 1080 rather than 1180 where it should have been. What should I do with this question?

Answer (score 1):

I concentrated on the memory clock. Turns out the GPU clock for GPU 4 is only 1090, which is what I put for hynix memory. For samsung memory, to reach 30.2 mh/s I should put 1180 GPU clock at least.

I guess mixing 2 types of GPU have it's drawback.